# Как переслать сообщение из одной группы в другую aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот состоит в обоих группах. Задача следующая. Нужно чтобы бот брал сообщение(не важно текст, фото, видео,звук) пользователя из одной группы и вставлял в другую группу но немного под другим видом.

Например: Пользователь из группу написал сообщение...
Бот корирует текст этого сообщения и вставляет его в группу2 в таком виде - Пользователь написал: текст сообщения.

Своего рода должно получитьться как логирование

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(chat_type=[types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def get_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id == "id первой группы":
        await bot.send_message(
            "id второй группы", 
            text= f"User {message.from_user.username}:\n" + message.text
        )
```

это для текстового сообщения, для остальных типов думаю разбирешься, просто добавляешь проверку на тип и в соответствии с этим выбираешь нужный метод для отправки

Comment: Не работает. Бот в обоих группах админ.